# Why mockServer.verify is needed in MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

When using [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) with `andExpect` to test

> ```
> mockServer.expect(requestTo("/hotels/42")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
>     .andRespond(withSuccess("{ \"id\" : \"42\", \"name\" : \"Holiday Inn\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
> ```

Then test failed if found unexpected behavior,

For example `no further requests expected: HTTP` if sent to unexpected URL

My Config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "..." })
public class MyConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

My Test class

```
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {MyConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class My Test extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private ServiceUnderMock serviceUnderMock;
private AutoCloseable closeable;

@BeforeClass
public void initMocks() {       
    closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
}

@AfterClass
public void releaseMocks() throws Exception {
    closeable.close();
}

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
@Test
public void test() {
    try {
        mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.min(1), 
          requestTo(new URI("https://www.google.com")))
          .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Assert.fail("failed to create mock");
    }    
    serviceUnderMock.doSomething();   
}
```

So why we need to add the `mockServer.verify()`?

> At the end of the test use verify() to ensure all expected requests were actually performed.

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more context? The test setup and also the full exception/failed assertion.

Comment: @rieckpil Added context

Comment: What Spring Boot test annotations are you using on top of your class? Right now it's a bit confusing as you first state that you're using `mockServer.expect(requestTo("/hotels/42"))` but then within the test you mock a request to Google? Can you clarify?

Comment: @rieckpil hotels are from documentation link, added class annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of `MockRestServiceServer` is that it allows you mock the external server such that the `RestTemplate` does not really need to send the requests to the actual server during the testing. Instead it just sends the requests to this `MockRestServiceServer` (think that it is a kind of in-memory server) and it will return the configured mocked responses for the corresponding requests.

You have to configure all the expected requests that the `MockRestServiceServer` will received and its corresponding responds  before the test.

So basically there are two things needed to be verified which are :

1. For every request sent by `RestTemplate` , there should be a mocked response configured for that request in the `MockRestServiceServer`
2. For all the requests that are to be expected to be received on the `MockRestServiceServer` , the RestTemplate should really send out all of these expected requests.

(1) will be verified automatically whenever the `RestTemplate` send out a request. The exception `no further requests expected: HTTP` that you mentioned is because it fails (1) (i.e. forget to stub this request in the `MockRestServiceServer`)

(2) will not be verified automatically . You have to call `MockRestServiceServer.verify()` manually in order to verify it.

An example :

```java
mockServer.expect(requestTo(new URI("https://www.yahoo.com")))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET)).andRespond(withSuccess());
        
mockServer.expect(requestTo(new URI("https://www.google.com")))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET)).andRespond(withSuccess());
        
        
mockServer.expect(requestTo(new URI("https://www.stackoverflow.com")))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET)).andRespond(withSuccess());

restTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.yahoo.com", String.class);
restTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.google.com", String.class);
```

Without `mockServer.verify()` , the test still passes although `RestTemplate` does not send the request to `https://www.stackoverflow.com` which the MockServer is expected to be received.

But with `mockServer.verify()` , it can check that and hence fails the test.